# SonarQube custom rule - getting method parameter owner class

Tags: java, tree, sonarqube

Currently I am working on fixing custom sonar rule.

```
private void reportMethodParametersClassContainingInternalAnnotation(MethodTree methodTree) {
    if (!methodTree.parameters().isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < methodTree.parameters().size(); i++) {
            if (!isParameterWrapperType(methodTree, i) && parameterClassContainsInternalAnnotation(methodTree, i)) {
                reportIssue(methodTree.parameters().get(i),
                        methodTree.parameters().get(i).type().symbolType().fullyQualifiedName()
                                + " class must be annotated @CanInvoke or must be standart java class");
            }
        }
    }
}

private static final ArrayList<String> WRAPPER_TYPES = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Boolean", "Character",
        "Byte", "Short", "Integer", "Long", "Float", "Double", "void", "String", "int"));

private static boolean isParameterWrapperType(MethodTree tree, int i) {
    return WRAPPER_TYPES.contains(tree.parameters().get(i).type().symbolType().name());
}

private boolean parameterClassContainsInternalAnnotation(MethodTree tree, int i) {
    return tree.parameters().get(i).type().symbolType().symbol().metadata()
            .isAnnotatedWith(Constants.INTERNAL_ANNOTATION_PATH);
}
```

This is the method, which search for parameters in method. After getting the one by one, method should check if parameter's class has @Internal annotation (custom annotation from my company). If it have it, method reports issue.
So far it is working working fine. But when it finds parameter which is Array of certain class, last method is trying to check not that class, but Array (which obviously does not have @Internal).

To be more clear this is example:

When method parameter is like this:

```
public void hello(SimpleClass simpleClass) {

}
```

last method returns:

```
true
```

and this:

```
tree.parameters().get(i).type().symbolType().symbol().name();
```

returns this:

```
SimpleClass
```

But when method parameter is like this:

```
public void hello(SimpleClass... simpleClass) {

}
```

last method returns:

```
false
```

and this:

```
tree.parameters().get(i).type().symbolType().symbol().name();
```

returns this:

```
Array
```

What method should be used to get this parameters real owner and be able to check if it is annotated with certain annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the type of the parameter you should check if it is an array and then you can cast to `Type.ArrayType` which has `elementType()` method returning the type of the array element.

Here is small example how to do this

```
MethodTree methodTree = (MethodTree) tree;
  for (VariableTree parameter : methodTree.parameters()) {
    Type parameterType = parameter.type().symbolType();
    if (parameterType.isArray()) {
      Type.ArrayType arrayType = (Type.ArrayType) parameterType;
      if (arrayType.elementType().symbol().metadata().isAnnotatedWith("MyAnnotation")) {
        // do something
      }
    }
  }
```